# Hibernate can not connect to MySQL from localhost

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have "inherited" some Java code that runs `Hibernate` to connect to `MariaDB`.

My user priviliges are set to:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR "userName"@"localhost";
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'XYZ';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MyDB1`.* TO 'userName'@'localhost';                                              
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MyDB2`.* TO 'userName'@'localhost';


SHOW GRANTS FOR "userName"@"%";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MyDB1`.* TO 'userName'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MyDB2`.* TO 'userName'@'%';
```

It's about localhost now: 
Connecting to `MyDB1` works from the `localhost-CLI (mysql -u unserName -p XYZ MyDB1)` and with `Hibernate`.

Connecting to `MyDB2` works from the `localhost-CLI (mysql -u unserName -p XYZ MyDB2)` but fails with `Hibernate`. Connecting with `Hibernate` from a remote machine works though?

Where should I look to fix this? I'm no super Java expert, but understand the code... 
I however believe the bug is in the DB somewhere...

Here are the Hibernate error messages:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
            at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
            at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
            at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
            at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
            at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
            at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
            at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userName'@'domainname' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2205)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2236)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2035)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: can you post the error messages?

Comment: Error logs are up

Comment: What I see is that hibernate converts `localhost` to the `machinename`. Could it be due to that? `localhost != machinename` yet they have the same `IP`?

Comment: `Access denied for user 'user'@'domainname'`  are you using the right username to access database?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be `userName` to be consistent with the above code.